# Detecting mouse click for the uppermost layered 2d sprite in Unity

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, mouse, layers

I have two sprites. One for the entire background and another small sprite, which is a foreground object. I have written code for both of these objects in their `OnMouseDown()` functions. When I click on the foreground object, the`MouseDown()`method of background object also gets called since it is behind the foreground.I just want my foreground sprite to react when I click it, not both foreground and background sprites.

Answer (score 1):

OnMouseDown() should normally work, make sure that both the sprites have separate scripts attached to them, with OnMouseDown() defined in each script. A collider should be attached to the script for the mouse click to work, in any case.

You can do debugging like this:

```
void OnMouseDown()
{
   Debug.Log(sprite.name);
}
```

Or still if things dont work, then try this piece of code instead

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition), out hit))
    {
        if (hit.collider == collider)
        {
            //Do your thing.
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah I already tried the first solution with Debug.Log(). It prints the name of the background.

Comment: If it prints the name of the background even when you click on your other object, please see if both the sprites are having different sorting layers. See if the z value of transform of both the sprites are different. You can visually see this by changing the 2D scene to 3D view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [RaycastAll](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.RaycastAll.html) and not [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.Raycast.html), as suggested by others.

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D[] hits = Physics2D.RaycastAll (mousePosition, new Vector2 (0, 0), 0.01f);
}
```

I would also suggest you tag your gameobject, and then use the tag to check if the object is the type you are looking for:

```
for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++) {
     if (hits [i].collider.tag == "Foreground")     
         //collider.GetComponent<ForegroundScript>().DoSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is to add raycaster to your sprites.

See this stackoverflow question for details :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529940/how-to-make-gameplay-ignore-clicks-on-ui-button-in-unity3d